# How to tell if a Principal Id is a permission group or a single user?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I'm using pnpJS to list all the users who have permissions on an SPO item:

```
 var info = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyList').items.getById(theId2).roleAssignments();
    console.log(info, 'info');
var info2 = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyList').roleAssignments.getById(3).groups();
    console.log(info2, 'groups');
    var newArr = info.map(a => a.PrincipalId);
    console.log(newArr, 'newArr');
    const res = newArr.forEach(async el => {
       await sp.web.siteUsers.getById(el).get().then(u => {
        console.log(u.Title);
      });
    });
```

I'm getting the list of users but if there is a group assigned to the SPO item, it throws an error. I need to deduce what is a group and what is a user so I can stop the `foreach` from including groups, therefore eliminating the error.

And for newArr log I get:

[image]

I know that Principal Id 3 is a group. I want the foreach to ignore any groups it returns. Successfully doing this would stop the error I'm getting.
I realise that roleAssigments may be looking for users instead of groups, which would cause the error. But how would I list any groups associated with the item?

Update (working code for anyone else):

```
const userIds = [];
    const userNames = [];
    const res = newArr.forEach(async el => {
      // console.log(el, 'el');
      try {
        await sp.web.siteUsers.getById(el).get().then(u => {
           console.log(u.Title);
           userNames.push(u.Title);
           userIds.push(el);
         });
       } catch (err) {
         console.error("looks like it wasn't user after all");
       }

     });
   this.setState({
     userIds: userIds,
     userNames: userNames
    },() => {
      console.log(this.state.userIds, 'userIds');
      console.log(this.state.userNames, 'userNames');
    });
 console.log("userIds: ", userIds); // see if you get your "good" ids here
 // vs
 console.log("user and group ids:", newArr);
```

Comment: what do the logs print for `info` and `newArr`? Are there some properties that distinguish groups vs users in data that you are working with?

Comment: I'll update my question with what you've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `info` data and it doesn't seem to provide any differentiators.

What you could potentially do to deal with this data is to add try / catch blocks and go on with whatever functionality you need, and get a list of actual users as you loop through.

// Certainly feels hacky but see if it helps

```
 var info = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyList').items.getById(theId2).roleAssignments();
    var newArr = info.map(a => a.PrincipalId);
    const userIds = []; // store collection of user ids that are not groups
    newArr.forEach(async el => {
      try {
       await sp.web.siteUsers.getById(el).get().then(u => {
          console.log(u.Title);
          userIds.push(el); // OR store actual user you get in response
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("looks like it wasn't user after all", err);
      }
    });

console.log("userIds: ", userIds); // see if you get your "good" ids here
// vs
console.log("user and group ids:", newArr);
```

Comment: I shall try this and report back! Thanks @Uma

Comment: no it's not working. I get Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'void' on the last line and also Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'any[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2016' or later.ts(2550) for 'includes' on the last line

Comment: I've update my question with something that might be useful.

Comment: you might actually not need to filter the results (in fact my advise to filter result of ForEach would never work as it just loops through array without creating new one). Let me update the answer

Comment: This works thanks to your help @Uma
I'll update my question with the answer